# Find out if a device is running my application over Wifi-Direct WITHOUT NETWORK SERVICES

Tags: android, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, wifi-direct

I understand that in Android API 16, the WifiP2pManager has an `addLocalService` method that can be used to query devices.

But how would I do this for API level 15?

Essentially I have one device as a Group Owner that sends constant updates to all its clients simultaneously.

The clients want to be able to subscribe to this content, so the Group Owner DOES NOT invite clients, clients just have to SEARCH for a group owner, and then once found, tell the group owner that they want to subscribe. Then the group owner stores the clients details and adds it to the recipient list.

Its simple discovering peers and seeing if they are a group owner. (Using a `PeerListListener` and the `WifiP2pDevice` method `isGroupOwner()`)

But how do I (as a client) search for all the group owners in range, and when I have a list of devices that are currently Group Owners, how do I check if that group is currently running my app?